# Swap order of integration of $\int_{0}^4\int_{0}^yf\left(x,y\right)\:dx\:dy$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am working through problems in my calc. III textbook and this is one I would like to verify. I must swap the order of integration of
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^4\int_{0}^yf\left(x,y\right)\:dx\:dy.\tag{1}
\end{align}
I think it is outlining a triangle below the line $y=x$ from $\left[0,4\right]$ along the $x$-axis (if that is so it would be the same interval along the $y$-axis). To swap I think I should end up at
\begin{align}
\int_0^x\int_0^4f\left(x,y\right)\:dy\:dx\tag{2}.
\end{align}
Is this right? It is not a homework problem.

Comment: Drawing a picture is generally very helpful for problems like these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's incorrect. The $x$-limits of integration should be constant. Look back to your graph of the triangle, call it $R$. A vertical line passing through $R$ enters at $y = x$ and leaves at $y = 4$ -- these give your $y$-limits of integration. The line sweeps out the region from $x = 0$ to $x = 4$ -- these give your $x$-limits of integration. So the result you're looking for is

$$\int_0^4 \int_x^4 f(x,y)\, dy\, dx.$$